# Unable to update logback configuration in Flink Native Kubernetes

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-cep

I have created a Flink Native Kubernetes (1.14.2) cluster which is successful. I am trying to update the logback configuration for which I am using the configmap exposed by Flink Native Kubernetes. Flink Native Kubernetes is creating this configmap during the start of the cluster and deleting it when the cluster is stopped and this behavior is as per the official documentation.

I updated the logback configmap which is also successful and this process even updates the actual logback files (conf folder) in the job manager and task manager. But Flink is not loading (hot reloading) this logback configuration.

Also I want to make sure that the logback configmap configuration is persisted even during cluster restarts. But the Flink Native Kubernetes recreates the configmap each time the cluster is started.

What is that I am missing here? How to make the updated logback configuration work?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can refer 'Configuring logback' in https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/advanced/logging/

Comment: I just got the solution via the Flink mailing list (https://lists.apache.org/thread/rwn2jx2qcjc8ms74jhf4nkvfncb01tvo).  I think the official documentation is missing this specific piece of information where we need to update the local conf folder which is used to create the configmap.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

To start Flink Native Kubernetes cluster, we will call kubernetes-session.sh. We just need to update the local conf folder before calling kubernetes-session.sh. The following are the files to be updated based on our requirements.

1. flink-conf.yaml
2. logger

   - logback-console.xml (when using logback)
   - log4j-console.properties (when using log4j)

#### How does it works

Basically the files from the local conf folder is used to create the configmap in Kubernetes which contains the above mentioned 3 files irrespective of whether you use logback or log4j. The contents from the configmap is then copied to the containers (jobmanager and taskmanager) when the containers are started.

[Reference](https://lists.apache.org/thread/rwn2jx2qcjc8ms74jhf4nkvfncb01tvo)

Thanks to Sharon Xie who gave the solution in the flink mailing list.